# failure in scraping the flight data table from airport website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to scrape arrival and departure data of domestic flights from the website of New Delhi International Airport.
I have tried almost everything but I cannot extract the data.
When I run the code, it returns nothing.I tried similar code on another airport website but it worked.
Here is the code I wrote.

```
res = requests.get("https://m.newdelhiairport.in/live-flight- information-all.aspx?FLMode=A&FLType=D")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'html5lib')
table = soup.find_all('tbody',{'class':'arr_dep_table_body'})
print(table)
```

Here is the link to the website:- "https://m.newdelhiairport.in/live-flight-information-all.aspx?FLMode=A&FLType=D"

[A screenshot of the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMC4m.png)

Comment: That page doesn't have any flight related info. The JavaScript makes an ajax call to https://m.newdelhiairport.in/get-all-Fids-FlightInfo.aspx?FltType=D&FltWay=A&FltNum=&FltFrom=&rn=0.4438762996837582 where the actual info is stored.

Comment: The link you derived. Can you please tell me how can I do it for other websites or other webpages ?

Comment: Just open your browser's inspector and watch the Network tab.

Comment: I tried but cannot do it. Can you please help me out with the link "https://csia.in/flightinformation/passenger-flight.aspx". I need to find the data for international flights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned you can use the alternative URL where the data is being source from. You will need to add a header.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://m.newdelhiairport.in/get-all-Fids-FlightInfo.aspx?FltType=D&FltWay=A&FltNum=&FltFrom=&rn=0.992638793938065'
re = requests.get(url, headers =  {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'})
df = pd.read_html(re.text)
print(df)
```

---

I pulled the URL from the network tab. I opened the network tab and re-loaded the page then inspected the XHR web traffic:

[image]

Comment: can you please explain the headers part ? Will the parameters be different in my laptop ?

Comment: I tried, it worked, but the tables are getting mixed up. What should I do about that ?

Comment: I am sorry. what I meant was columns are getting mixed up. For ex, status and ETA are coming in one column and in place of ETA, there is NONE.

Comment: Sure, whenever you are free. The problem is that there is an empty column VIA. And the values of other column is getting filled in it.

Comment: can you please let me know how did you get this link ?

Comment: please see my updated answer. Sorry for delay. Also, I got the url from the network tab via F12.

Comment: I tired but it is not working. Can you please provide me the link for this website :- "https://csia.in/flightinformation/passenger-flight.aspx". I need data of international flights.

Comment: I pressed F12 and it is closing the inspect element part and returning to the normal mode.

Comment: Yes I did, and it is running perfectly. Thank you for that

Comment: Can you help me find the link for the website I mentioned above, please ?

Comment: I think the number on the end of the URL is randomly generated (?)  to keep results fresh.

Comment: The issue with this link is that :"https://csia.in/flightinformation/passenger-flight.aspx" is that there is no output in the XHR Tab

Comment: The issue with this link is that :"https://csia.in/flightinformation/passenger-flight.aspx" is that there is no output in the XHR Tab. From this website, I am able to access only domestic flights data. Not international.

Comment: That is a different link and you can use pd.read_html https://pastebin.com/uvUgEkgv  Just check results are as expected.

Comment: It is also extracting the domestic flight data. Not International flight data.

Comment: any suggestions ?

Comment: In a meeting at mo

Comment: Please, whenever you are free.