# BS4 find_all not matching mini_card-title class from Genius Lyrics

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to get the title of a song from the genius lyrics' song search, however, using .find_all("div", class_="mini_card-title") to attempt to get the name of the song does not work, but .find_all("div" class_="header") does work!

This is just for a small project I am working on, running on visual studio 2019, with python 3.7. I am using 2 modules: requests and bs4. I have tried to change the parser, change find_all to find and to select, however none of these helped.

the code that doesn't work:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
a = soup.find_all("div", class_="mini_card-title")
print(a)
```

the code that does work:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
a = soup.find_all("div", class_="header")
print(a)
```

I expect to get the name of the song, even getting the names of all of the songs on the page will be fine, however currently I only get a blank list.

Comment: On what page for example? And what's the problem as one of the 2 methods works?

Comment: please supply url if possible

Comment: @Qharr , I am using the URL: https://genius.com/search?q=something in the following way: res = requests.get("https://genius.com/search?q=something")

Comment: Using the phrase "Not working" or "doesn't work" in a title is a good way to get a very negative response around here, as opposed to narrowly describing a specific and well-defined behavior ("returning no response when filtering by class", f/e).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the info by using the API the page uses to dynamically get results. I show printing out some titles but explore the json response to see what you want.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://genius.com/api/search/multi?per_page=5&q=something').json()
for item in r['response']['sections']:
    for subitem in item['hits']:
        if 'title' in subitem['result']:
            print(subitem['result']['title'])
```

Comment: Thank you very much! this fixed my issue perfectly. One question however: how did you get to that api page?(https://genius.com/api/search/multi?per_page=5&q=something') ? and how can I get to a similar api page on different websites?

Comment: I used the network tab (F12) to inspect the web traffic and refreshed the webpage. Then I used a value off the page and searched through the recorded web traffic.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53755324/failure-in-scraping-the-flight-data-table-from-airport-website/53755919#53755919